# Format PC without losing the data

Tags: windows-7, format

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Clean (re)install of Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/290281/clean-reinstall-of-windows-7)

Is there a way to format PC (Windows, Windows 7 to be precise) without losing the data in it?

Comment: Wait...? What? What exactly is it you would like that "format" to do?

Comment: This is like asking, "Is there a way to go swimming without touching water?". Take @Breakthrough's suggestion and tell us a bit more about what you want to do.

Comment: The *whole point* of formatting is to wipe the data. You’ll need to be more specific about what you are trying to accomplish. Failing that, we can only guess. (My guess is that you want to reinstall Windows without losing your files and settings; in which case, yes, it is possible to back-up and migrate them.)

Comment: Yes, the last comment is correct. I need to reinstall Windows without losing my files

Comment: the point of format is __ not wiping the data, so the named ' format' is to change or renew the format

Comment: It sounds to me your goal is not to format the drive, but do something else. You should ask that something else instead. Like "my file system is of wrong type, how do I convert it without losing data"?

Answer (score 9):

Don't ask what you *think* needs to be done.  Post what your actual problem is, because I think you're asking the wrong question.

If you corrupted Windows and just want to boot into the computer to get some files on an external drive, you can just install Windows overtop of the existing partition (just don't format it), and then you should be able to boot up the computer.

Alternatively, you can use the [UBCD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/) to resize your existing partition, install Windows on a new one, move your files over, then format the original one, and then move the files back and re-merge the partitions.

---

Oh, and just an FYI, formatting *is* deleting all data.  It basically clears the partition's filesystem information, as well as all of the file tables and directory structures.

Comment: Formatting generally does _not_ alter the partition table or the MBR.  That would be _repartitioning_.  Formatting only deals with the contents of an individual volume.

Comment: @JdeBP correct, answer updated.

Answer (score 3):

If by data you mean your documents, sure thing. Just move them to different partition (create one if you haven't, reformat the system drive with Windows installer, and now you get a fresh Windows booting up. If you mean you need the applications too, well, be prepare to backup the settings (they can be anywhere) and find the original installer

Answer (score 1):

The point of formatting a hard drive is to wipe out the data. If you want to reinstall Windows and format the hard drive but keep your files such as pictures, documents etc, make backup copies and put them on another storage device such as on a:

- CD
- DVD
- USB Drives
- External Hard Drives
- A separate hard drive in your computer that you're not going to format
- A hard drive on your network

Do note, that for wiping out data formatting is very bad option. Use proper disk wipe tools instead. For example, boot from Linux Live CD and run "shred -vz -n 3 /dev/sda" or similar.

Comment: Only use the tools if you want to completely wipe out the data on your hard drive with slim chance of recovering any of it.

Use normal format if you're just going to do a simple reinstall of your OS

Answer (score 0):

Your question is to vague.  You can convert a filesystem from fat32 to NTFS without destroying data with the following command

convert c: /fs:ntfs